# Stripped symbols are not hidden from strings linux tool

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, stripping

I have a shared library with the symbols stripped. Using a known method/tool to get the symbol names (like `nm -D`, `objdump`, `readelf`, etc) I see that all the symbols are actually hidden.

However, if I run the `strings` linux tool on my shared library, I can see some of those symbols exposed. I made sure I don't print any of those symbols in messages, but it still somehow prints the symbols that I expect to be stripped.

So, my question is, how can I hide my symbols even from the `strings` command line tool in linux? Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:
I am using `strip -strip--all` to hide the static symbols and I also enable the `-fvisibility=hidden` compile flag to hide the unneeded dynamic symbols.

Comment: See [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/elfkickers.html) for `sstrip`.

Comment: If this is a C++ library, consider compiling without RTTI (`-fno-rtti`) to avoid leaking symbols via included type information. (Disabling RTTI also helps make reverse engineering harder).

Comment: it's actually a C library so i can't use -fno-rtti

Comment: Which ELF section are these unwanted symbol names in?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from `man strings`:

> <sup>DESCRIPTION</sup>
>
> <sup>For  each  file  given,  GNU `strings` prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long.</sup>

The difference between `strings` and the tools mentioned by you (`readelf`, `objdump`, etc) is that those rely mostly on the DWARF information embedded in the ELF object, whereas the `strings` utility outputs *ANY* printable sequence from the binary data (DWARF unrelated).

*How can I hide my symbols even from the `strings` utility:* [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47/can-i-create-an-object-file-using-gcc-that-cannot-be-reverse-engineered) could be of help.